# mySQL Fatal Error - Can't Figure It Out

Tags: mysql

I have the following error from this sql query:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/runestak/public_html/php/deposit/depositTicket.php on line 84

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ticketsDB (userID, depositWallet, depositAmount, depositCurrency, ingame-name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $accountID, $depositWallet, $depositGP, $gameServer, $ingameName);

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: I think your sql statement is not correct according to your DB thats why prepare statement always return false statement. Can you please post your complete code including your `$conn` variable and database table `ticketsDB` structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful  ..to the column namimg seems you are using minus in column name  .. this could cause an error  try  using backticks around

```
"INSERT INTO ticketsDB (userID, depositWallet, depositAmount, depositCurrency, `ingame-name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

or could be yiu are using wrong name eg you need `ingame_name`

Comment: Thanks buddy, that was the issue, something new I've learn't :)